# Drush isn't able to download updates

Tags: drush, files

My sys admin hasn't made any changes to dir permissions, but lately whenever I run DRUSH UP I get the following error:

> [error] Unable to download drupal-7.43.tar.gz to /srv/www/htdocs from 
>   https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.43.tar.gz Updating
>   project drupal failed.

I'm running Drupal 7.41 with MySQL 5.5.31 and PHP 5.3.17.
Clearing my caches, running "drush rf" followed by "drush up drupal" doesn't work either.
Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Did you check the directory has write permission for the user you are currently using to run the command?